# mount network drive

Tags: 11.04, mount, fstab

since i updated my ubuntu to natty narwhal(from 10.04), my mount script doesn't work anymore.

The scripts mounts a folder from a NAS (WD mybookworld) in the local network to a folder in my home folder.

script looked like that:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo mount //192.168.2.222/Public/Shared\ Music/ /home/simon/Musik/
```

error:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on //192.168.2.222/Public/Shared Music/,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error
   (for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might
   need a /sbin/mount.<type> helper program)
   Manchmal liefert das Syslog wertvolle Informationen – versuchen
   Sie  dmesg | tail  oder so
```

now, because the script doesn't work anymore i decided to add the mount-process to my fstab, because the network drive should be mounted on every startup.

My fstab entry looks like this:

```
//192.168.2.222/Public/Shared\ Music/ /home/simon/Musik cifs credentials=/home/simon/.smbcredentials 0 0
```

But it doesn't work, too. I get a message during the startup process, that Musik couldn't be mounted.

Are there any log files i can check for errors?
The system is a fresh installed 11.04.

Greetings

Comment: your answers fixed the mount issue.  and for the fstab entry, i had to replace the space with a \040  and now everything works. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear, it does not recognize the filesystem type.
`/sbin/mount.cifs` is provided by the `cifs-utils` package, you need to install that package for mounting Samba shares.

Answer (score 5):

Try `sudo apt-get install smbfs`.  That should re-install the necessary CIFS helpers need to mount the drive.  Not sure why this would suddenly stop working after an upgrade though.

Comment: It looks like that package isn't available anymore; cifs-utils should work instead

Answer (score 2):

Works for me with:

```
sudo apt-get install cifs-utils
```

Answer (score 1):

if you already have the correct file system installed, you could specify which file system to use in your [`mount`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man8/mount.8.html) command:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.2.222/Public/Shared\ Music/ /home/simon/Musik/
```

Answer (score 0):

From a fresh install I did:

```
sudo apt-get install samba smbfs
```